# How to get Spyder to automatically change python interpreter/env when opening an existing project?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, spyder

**Summary**

Goal - I want to assign a particular conda enviroment/python interpreter to individual Spyder projects such that when I open said projects, the the appropriate corresponding interpreter is automatically changed in Spyder preferences > python interperter (Similar to creating projects in other IDEs e.g. PyCharm).

Problem - Dispite my best efforts, I have to always manually change Spyder's preferences in order to set the correct interpreter (work in different environments). This is tedious and may cause issues in the future if I every forget which is the correct environment corresponding to a project

**What I've tried so far**

Setup - First, I create a new environment via conda with python and spyder-kernels installed using the following command `conda create --name project1 python spyder-kernels`. Next, I open Spyder in my base environment and create a new project called "project1" and set the python interpreter path to `...envs\project1\python.exe`. At this point everything is working as expected. Now, I repeat this process for a new project2 and again everything works great. The issue comes up when I move back to project1, the interpreter will still be set to `...envs\project2\python.exe` rather than switch automatically to `...envs\project1\python.exe`.

This post seems to suggest that there would be a full environment manager in Spyder 4 but I can't seem to find it anywhere https://www.spyder-ide.org/blog/release-spyder-330/.

Reference for setting up spyder-kernels: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

**Background**

Python 3, Windows 10, Miniconda Distribution

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but you could write a short script, that loads a config file with that correct interpreter and env setup for each project. Or maybe the IDE has an option for pre-build/pre-run tasks, like visual studio.